# Invalid json primitive: passing a unique identifier to an asmx web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I finally got my web method somewhat working, but now I'm trying to get it to return just the json object.  My javascript method is below:

```
function PopulateRooms(e) {
           var idx = e.selectedIndex;
           var dcId = JSON.stringify('{ dataCenterId:' + e.options[idx].value + '}', null, 2);
           var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService/AVWebService.asmx")%>';

           $.ajax({
               url: pageUrl + '/GetRooms',
               type: 'post',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: dcId,
               success: OnRoomsReceived,
               error: OnErrorCall
           });
       }
```

dcId is a Unique Identifier. I'm targetting only new browsers, so I read that I don't need another library, I can just use the JSON.stringify() method.  But when I do, I get a Error 500: Cannot convert object of type \u0027\System.String\u0027 to type  ...IDictionary.

However, if I take the JSON.stringify() out, I get an Invalid JSON primitive error.  How do I pass an id to my web method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a js string to json, what you want is to convert an object to json,

```
var dcId = JSON.stringify({ dataCenterId: e.options[idx].value });
```

Comment: I tried the other suggestions, they resulted in Invalid JSON primitives. This worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need the stringify at all, as $.Ajax data property takes a javascript object:

```
var dcId = { dataCenterId: e.options[idx].value };
```

Comment: OP wants to send json, jQuery.ajax converts objects to url-encoded data not json. So you have to pass json if you want to send it.